# How to customize the View in spring roo 2.0.0.M2

Tags: spring-roo

How to customize the View/template html in spring roo 2.0.0.M2?
What is equivalent of z="user-managed" or render="false" in spring roo 2.0.0.M2?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Roo 2.0.0.M2 is just a milestone. The feature that you're talking about has not been migrated to 2.x version yet.

If you want, you could create a new issue on https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO/

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for the reply @jcgarcia.

Comment: Is the feature z="user-managed" or render="false" now available in Spring Roo 2.0.0 ?

Comment: Thank you @jcgarcia for your quick reply.

Comment: I tried but both data-z="user-managed" and  render="false" are not working... I need to change one of the input field type from "text" to "password" and each time it's getting overwritten by roo.

Comment: Try to include it in a parent element like span, div, instead directly in the element.